# Find the interior, closure, and boundary of a given set, in the Euclidean and discrete metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I got subset A displayed in image. I'm trying to find Closure, Interior and Boundary  in $d^{(2)}$ and $d^{(0)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Here:

- $d^{(2)}$ is Euclidean metric,
- $d^{(0)}$ is discrete metric

[image: 1]

So subset A to be clear is $A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : -4<x^2+y^2<-1 , -4<x<-1\}$.

I think interior is same as the set in $d^{(2)}$. But the Closure and Boundary and discrete metric are more tricky.

Comment: i think interior is same as the set in d(2) how about  Closure and Boundary and discrete metric thats more tricky!!

Comment: As long as you do not explain what you mean by d(2) and d(0), no one can help you.

Comment: You are right. Int(A) = A. What do you think is the closure?

Comment: it is inside this set , the problem is to write in set notation i have problem with that!  if it was closed set Cl(A) = A but it is kind of nearly open